# Unbold text in bullets

Tags: bold

How to unbold text while using bullets for example:

`\item[$\bullet$ text]`

it produce bold **text**?
how to converts it to normal text?

Comment: Hello, if you provided a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), it would be easier to see what's going on. The idea by Romain Picot works for a single case, but if you had to do it for every `\item` in the document, something would be very wrong.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

`normalfont` permits to have your text as the main part of your document:

`\item[$\bullet${\normalfont text}}`

The following should work too:

`\item[$\bullet$] text`

Comment: @user87834 You're welcome, you can accept the answer if it's useful: "you should thank [user] by upvoting [his/her] answer (with the upward pointing arrow to the left of it; you need 15 reputation points before you can upvote) and accepting it (by clicking on the checkmark ✓)." (from meta)

Comment: How to reduce spacing between two lines with bullets?

Comment: @user87834 : this seems to be another question and so you should ask a new one if you didn't found the answer on TeX.SE

Comment: @user87834 I'm sure that both your questions actually _have_ and answer on the site already. But you [***DO NOT PROVIDE A CLEAR EXAMPLE OF WHAT YOU ARE DOING***](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), so it's impossible to truly help you. Actually, exactly **zero** of your **six** questions meet the lowest standards of question quality, in my opinion.